# (Statistics) actual data generating function from experimental data set

Tags: statistics

[image]

The data Sets are given in the picture, where $Y$ is the actual data (current) and $Z$ is the experimental data and both data are achieved with respect to $X$.

Now If I get an ADC value $z=200$, what is the respective actual current value $y$? And how it can be calculated from the above data only?

Comment: What are the possible values of $y$? Is it all nonnegative integers? Is it a finite number of categories? Can it take on decimal values?

Comment: y is positive rational number , may be integers or may be fraction. y=f(x), and z=g(x) i have those function from the image data sets using linear or non linear regression. now i want to build a function like this : y=f(z,x)  or y=f(z) or something like that. sure it can take decimal values

Comment: If you have $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ explicitly, and you can find $g^{-1}$, then $y = f(g^{-1}(z))$. Or, you can say $h = f \circ g^{-1}$, then $y = h(z)$.